# How to deal with touchpad issue and if can't, change versios?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I bought a new Acer Aspire E15 this week and when I went to install Ubuntu 14.04, the touchpad didn't work so I plugged in a usb mouse and installed. The touchpad still did not work once installation was complete. xinput --a did not list the touchpad. I upgraded to 14.10 and the touchpad worked, but it keeps crashing every now and then (seems to be only when I'm watching video) and restarting. So, I want to revert back to 14.04 and somehow keep the trackpad working. Can someone please give me advice on how to do this.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought an Acer Aspire E15 as well. The trackpad wouldn't work at all on Ubuntu 14.04. I managed to get the trackpad working by pressing F2 during boot (when you see the Acer logo) and changing the trackpad setting from 'Advanced' to 'Basic'... The only problem is that in this setting, two-finger scrolling doesn't work...

Comment: thanks for the response. I couldn't find the trackpad option in the screen that comes up after pressing F2 during boot. Where is it exactly? thanks

Comment: Arrow over to the right. It's under 'MAIN'. Then arrow down to the touchpad setting. Hit Enter to change the setting. Then Hit F10 to save changes and exit.

Comment: I can't seem to find it on my laptop. Under main are the options: System Time, System Date, Total Memory, Network Boot, F12 boot menu, D2D Recovery, Wake on LAN. That's it, no mention on touchpad...

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to get trackpad to work, without modifying bios settings:

```
sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
```

See Ubuntu Forums for this:
[touchpad not recognised acer aspire e15 e5-572g-5577](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244174)